# Change the dependency of \maketitle command

Tags: titles, document-classes

I am trying to develop a class file for my department. I want to add two dependencies to the `\maketitle` command. As we have `\title` & `\author` as compulsory commands for `\maketitle`, I want `\supervisor` and as we have `\date` which is optional, I want `\subtitle`. I have tried the following code. It's not working. What mistake am I committing?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ML}[2020/01/24 MWE class-file]

\LoadClass{book}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\textsc{supervisor : #1}}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\textsc{}}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \makeatletter
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \fboxsep3em
    \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}
            [c][\dimexpr\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]
            [c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
            \begin{center}
                \bigskip
                \textbf{{\LARGE \textsc{\@title}}%\\
                    %\vspace{0.2cm}
                    %{\@subtitle}
                }
                \\
                \vfill
                {\large\textsc{\@author}}\\
                %   \vspace{0.5in}
                %   {\large \@supervisor}
                \vspace{0.5in}
                \textsc{\@date}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}}
        \makeatother}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below given modified `MWE`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ML}[2020/01/24 MWE class-file]

\LoadClass{book}
\let\@superwiser\@empty%
\def\superwiser#1{\def\@superwiser{\textsc{superwiser :#1}}}%

\let\@subtitle\@empty%
\def\subtitle#1{\def\@subtitle{\textsc{#1}}}%

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \makeatletter
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \fboxsep3em
    \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}
            [c][\dimexpr\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]
            [c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
            \begin{center}
                \bigskip
                \textbf{{\LARGE \textsc{\@title}}\\
                    \vspace{0.2cm}
                    {\@subtitle}
                }
                \\
                \vfill
                {\large\textsc{\@author}}\\
                   \vspace{0.5in}
                   {\large \@superwiser}\\
                \vspace{0.5in}
                \textsc{\@date}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}}
        \makeatother}

\endinput
```

**Usage**

```
\documentclass{ML}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}

\superwiser{Name}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```